# How can I tidyup and fix my Python installation on Kali

Tags: python, linux, nmap

so I suspect I have a Python installation problem. I was doing some coding in python. Everything was running just fine then it just stopped loading scapy for no particular reason at all. Unable to import Scapy. I tried lots of things and in the end gave up on it as it was taking too long to figure out and wasn't really that important anyway.

So now I am doing something else that has a Python dependency. I am using Maltego with some custom transforms that I have downloaded. They are Python dependent and getting these transforms working will save me a ton of time.

The error in Maltego when it runs is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/maltego-nmap/units/nmap_xml_parser.py", line 4, in <module>
from lxml             import etree
ImportError: No module named lxml
```

The python root path in maltego is shown as /usr/bin/python

So I checked my python path:

```
KALI606:/usr/bin# type -a python
python is /usr/bin/python
python is /bin/python

KALI606:/usr/bin# cd bin/python
bash: cd: bin/python: No such file or directory
KALI606:/usr/bin# cd usr/bin/python
bash: cd: usr/bin/python: No such file or directory

KALI606:/usr/bin# ls -l python*
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Nov 18 06:36 python -> python2                                           
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Nov 18 06:36 python2 -> python2.7                                        
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3647800 Jan 19 19:54 python2.7                                                   
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Jan 19 19:54 python2.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config       
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Nov 18 06:36 python2-config -> python2.7-config                          
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     385 Feb  2 03:10 python2-futurize                                            
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     389 Feb  2 03:10 python2-pasteurize                                          
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Nov 14 14:13 python3 -> python3.7                                        
    -rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 5114928 Mar 10 13:18 python3.7                                                   
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Mar 10 13:18 python3.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.7-config       
    -rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 5114928 Mar 10 13:18 python3.7m                                                  
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      34 Mar 10 13:18 python3.7m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.7m-config     
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5453504 Feb 25 13:04 python3.8
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Nov 14 14:13 python3-config -> python3.7-config
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     384 Feb  2 03:10 python3-futurize
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     398 Sep  7  2018 python3-jsonschema
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Nov 14 14:13 python3m -> python3.7m
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      17 Nov 14 14:13 python3m-config -> python3.7m-config
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     388 Feb  2 03:10 python3-pasteurize
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     364 Dec 15 18:09 python3-qr
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     196 Oct  6  2019 python3-tor-prompt
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    5902 Oct  1  2018 python3-wsdump
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      14 Nov 18 06:36 python-config -> python2-config
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Feb  4 14:30 python-faraday -> faraday
```

This is a mess right?

Any suggestions on how I can sort out Python pls? I feel like I want to just remove all python references and start clean but I have limited knowledge on this. The Maltego error is very similar to the scapy error I had.

I am running the latest version of Kali.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `python2-lxml` with something like

```
sudo apt-get install python2-lxml
```